# React: Data not showing until page refreshes

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am currently building a simple CRUD workflow using React and GraphQL. After I create an object (an `article` in this case which just has an `id`, `title` and `description`.), I navigate back to an `Index` page which displays all of the currently created articles. My issue is that after an article is created, the index page does not display the created article until I refresh the page. I am using `apollo` to query the graphql api and have disabled cacheing on it so I'm not sure why the data isn't displaying. I've set breakpoints in my `ArticlesIndex`'s `componentDidMount` function and ensured that it is executing and at the time of executing, the database does include the newly added `article`.

My server side is actually never even hit when the client side query to retrieve all articles executes. I'm not sure what is cacheing this data and why it is not being retrieved from the server as expected.

My `ArticlesCreate` component inserts the new record and redirects back to the `ArticlesIndex` component as follows:

```
handleSubmit(event) {  
    event.preventDefault();  
    const { client } = this.props;

    var article = {
      "article": {
        "title": this.state.title,
        "description": this.state.description
      }
    };

    client
    .mutate({ mutation: CREATE_EDIT_ARTICLE, 
      variables: article })
    .then(({ data: { articles } }) => {
        this.props.history.push("/articles");  
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("err", err);
    });

  }
}
```

then my `ArticlesIndex` component retrieves all articles from the db as follows:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const { client } = this.props; //client is an ApolloClient
    client
    .query({ query: GET_ARTICLES })
    .then(({ data: { articles } }) => {
        if (articles) {
          this.setState({ loading: false, articles: articles });
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("err", err);
    });
};
```

and I've set ApolloClient to not cache data as in my `App.js` as follows:

```
const defaultApolloOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    errorPolicy: 'ignore',
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
}

export default class App extends Component {
  displayName = App.name;

  client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://localhost:44360/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    defaultOptions: defaultApolloOptions
  });

  //...render method, route definitions, etc
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Assuming `articles` is an array `this.setState({ loading: false, articles: [...articles] });`? Or is JSON that needs to be parsed?

Comment: `articles` is indeed an array however setting the state is working correctly. The issue as far as I've nailed it down is that `articles` in the `.then` callback of my query in `componentDidMount` contains stale data (from before the create call was executed)

Comment: How are you navigating back? Browsers back Button or calling your Index component?

Comment: `this.props.history.push("/articles");  ` in the `ArticlesCreate` component (that route is for the `ArticlesIndex` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with `ApolloBoost` not supporting `defaultOptions` as noted [in this github issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3900). To resolve the issue I changed:

```
const defaultApolloOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    errorPolicy: 'ignore',
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
}

export default class App extends Component {
  displayName = App.name;

  client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://localhost:44360/graphql",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    defaultOptions: defaultApolloOptions
  });

  //...render method, route definitions, etc
}
```

To:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://localhost:44360/graphql"
});

client.defaultOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    errorPolicy: 'ignore',
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
};

export default class App extends Component {
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are getting the data and setting your components state on initial mount. Most probably when you redirect it doesn't fire the componentDidMount lifecylcle hook as it is already mounted, if that is the issue try using [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle hook so that your component knows there was an update and re-set the data.

Comment: He is setting the state so render should be evoked. You should be making calls to the backend from `componentDidMount` and not `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: I can confirm that `componentDidMount` is being called after my create component redirects back to my index component. However for some reason the query doesn't seem to actually be executing and its working off stale data. (`articles` in the callback isn't up to date but this code is executing)